# Finding variance from normal distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, variance, multivariate-normal-distribution

Suppose $Z_1$ and $Z2$ ~$N(0,1)$

Let $X_1=2Z_1$ and $X_2=X_1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}Z_2$

Let $Y_1=\sqrt{3}Z_1+Y_2$ and $Y_2=Z_2$

I understand I have to show the mean and variance for $X_1$ and $X_2$ should be the same as the mean and variance for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ in order to show X and Y have the same distribution.

The mean for X and Y are the same: $[ 0, 0]^T$

However I got $[\sigma^2_{X_1}, \sigma^2_{X_2}]=[4, 4+\frac{3}{4}]$ and $[\sigma^2_{Y_1}, \sigma^2_{Y_2}]=[4, 1]$

This is my work so far:
$$\sigma^2_{X_2} = \sigma^2_{X_1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}Z_2}$$
$$= \sigma^2_{X_1}+\sigma^2_{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}Z_2}$$
$$= \sigma^2_{2Z_1}+\frac{3}{4}\sigma^2_{Z_2}$$
$$= 4\sigma^2_{Z_1}+\frac{3}{4}\sigma^2_{Z_2}$$
$$= 4+\frac{3}{4}$$
and
$$\sigma^2_{Y_2} = \sigma^2_{Z_2} = 1$$

Did I make any mistake here?
It seems like $Y_2$ should be equal to $X_2$, but not...

Comment: and $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent

Comment: If there are no typos, $X$ and $Y$ don't have the same distribution. They should have the same covariance matrix btw. equating variances is not enough.